# ERROR: ld.so: object 'libgtk3-nocsd.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gtk3, hugo

Running into this issue when working with Hugo and the AWS CLI on Ubuntu 18.04.

```
ERROR: ld.so: object 'libgtk3-nocsd.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (failed to map segment from shared object): ignored.
```

This is a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04, Hugo, and AWS CLI.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libgtk3-nocsd0:i386` fixed for me.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Found the answer after a bit of web searching here: https://github.com/PX4/Firmware/issues/9409

### Solution

If you update your `.bashrc` with the below line it should fix the issue:

```
export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0
```

In addition, you may need to install the following package:

```
sudo apt install gtk3-nocsd
```

### An Alternative

Another user reported installing the following package fixed their issue:

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk3-nocsd0:i386
```

Comment: I'm running on an iMAC and running Ubuntu in a virtual machine, this fix doesn't work for me, the folder x86_64-linux-gnu doesn't exist on my system.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?  I haven't tried this on a VM.  This was on a Dell laptop.

Comment: The version of Ubuntu was 18.04

Comment: In Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, there is no i386 build of libgtk3-nocsd0, so `sudo apt-get install libgtk3-nocsd0:i386` will fail with `E: Unable to locate package libgtk3-nocsd0:i386`. I have attempted to get round this by installing the 18.04 DEB on 20.04: Manually download `libgtk3-nocsd0_3-1ubuntu1_i386.deb` and install with `sudo dpkg -i libgtk3-nocsd0_3-1ubuntu1_i386.deb`. This seems to work for me.

Comment: Can't download libgtk3-nocsd0_3-1ubuntu1_i386.deb, checked almost all mirrors from 
 https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/i386/libgtk3-nocsd0/download. Please share if any valid mirror available.

Comment: This is basically installing unneeded package just to fix warnings ;). Just remove that old stuff like I described below.

Comment: Will this brick other applications that depend on LD_PRELOAD? Is LD_PRELOAD "additive" (and any apps requested preloads will add onto this), or will they be/this replaced by the most recent LD_PRELOAD?

Comment: I'd say, a better addition to the `.bashrc` is `[ -e /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0 ] && export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0`.

Comment: In Kubuntu 20.04 the package that needs to be installed is `libgtk3-nocsd0`. No need to install `gtk3-nocsd`.

Answer (score 12):

Running

```
$ sudo grep -r LD_PRELOAD /etc $HOME
```

I found lots of configuration files of the removed package `gtk3-nocsd` like

```
/etc/X11/Xsession.d/51gtk3-nocsd-detect: export LD_PRELOAD="libgtk3-nocsd.so.0${LD_PRELOAD:+:$LD_PRELOAD}"
```

Just remove those old configuration with:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge gtk3-nocsd
```

Comment: This is the right answer if you upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04 and start seeing this error

Comment: @Andrei-Emeltchenko Amazing. I just followed these exact same steps before discovering your answer. It worked like a charm. BTW : My Ubuntu 20.04 LTS comes from an Ubuntu 18.04 LTS upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

in file /etc/X11/Xsession.d/51gtk3-nocsd-detect
change the line # 22 to

```
export LD_PRELOAD="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0"
```