# ERROR: LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded :ignored

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, wine, ld-preload

I just [installed wine](https://tecadmin.net/install-wine-on-ubuntu/) from [this link](https://tecadmin.net/install-wine-on-ubuntu/) to run windows applications in my ubuntu 18.04(Bionic beaver) but when i run `wine --version` the output was

```
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64): ignored.
wine-4.0.1
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53825858/9756427) solution but it didn't work for me so now here I am asking a similar question.

Comment: What exactly have you tried? Have you tried suggestion from the first comment to the question (install 32-bit version of the library?)  Did you get the same error message after you tried the solution?

Comment: @VladislavIvanishin https://stackoverflow.com/a/53825858/9756427, is what i tried.

Comment: YeahI tried that but it didnt work.

Comment: `$ sudo apt-get install libgtk3-nocsd0:i386
[sudo] password for nischaya: 
Swipe your finger across the fingerprint reader
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libgtk3-nocsd0:i386 is already the newest version (3-1ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`

`$ wine --version
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64): ignored.
wine-4.0.1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a side effect of installing the [gtk3-nocsd](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/gtk3-nocsd) package. On 64-bit systems, it sets the `LD_PRELOAD` environment variable in a way that is incompatible with 32-bit multi-arch binaries. The error message is harmless. You can try removing the  gtk3-nocsd package if you do not need it (`apt remove gtk3-nocsd` as root), or set the `LD_PRELOAD` environment variable when launching Wine:

```
LD_PRELOAD= wine
```