# LXC container running on Ubuntu gives linker errors (ERROR: ld.so)

Tags: ubuntu, containers, archlinux, lxc

I have the following setup:

- I have an archlinux LXC container running on a Ubuntu 18.04 LTS host.
- No matter what command I execute, I get the following error:

> [root@archie /]# pacman -Syu 
>   ERROR: ld.so: object 'libgtk3-nocsd.so.0'
>   from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.

- I have `libgtk3-nocsd` installed on the host Ubuntu 18.04 (even though I don't think that that matters as the error only happens when executing commands inside the archlinux container).
- As far as I know this `libgtk3-nocsd.so.0` is a Debian/Ubuntu specific library which should not really be present or needed on archlinux. Anyways `pacman -Ss` for `nocsd` or similar sounding names turned up empty.

My problem is similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53825857/error-ld-so-object-libgtk3-nocsd-so-0-from-ld-preload-cannot-be-preloaded) but none of the solutions mentioned for that question work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved that problem today.

1. From the discussion [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/aaih49/arch_equivalent_packages_to_libgtk3dev_and/), I realized that for arch the equivalent packet is gtk3 (and NOT `libgtk3` nor `libgtk3-dev` nor `libgtk3-nocsd`, as I was originally searching).
2. From [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GTK#Installation) I found out that I need to install the `gtk3` package by issuing the command:

```
# pacman -Syu gtk3
```

3. And then following from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53825858/2955790) for Ubuntu, I tried something similar for arch, as shown below:

```
#export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libgtk-3.so.0
```

and now the error no longer appears.

*(If not obvious, all of these steps were done inside the arch container, of course.)*